# Trigger python script with new RSS item

Tags: python, rss, raspbian

I have written a small python parser for a website, in order to extract the main news of a certain section. I would now like to trigger that script every time a new item is added to the website, using the RSS feeds. I am running Raspbian. Is there any utility to warn me of such event?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of research, I found the `rsstail`utility thanks to this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22137/how-to-watch-rss-feed-for-new-entries-from-bash-script). The only problem was that after a few minutes, it would either fail or quit completely. So I found [this](https://github.com/gvalkov/rsstail.py), which is exactly the same thing, only written in python and does not crash (at least for me). What I did then was set up a small bash script, which gets executed at startup, using `crontab`. The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsstail -i 15 --initial 1 http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=us | while read line
  do
    /Users/aUser/Desktop/myScript.py
  done
```

This means that every time a new item is added, the script `myScript.py` gets executed. Just remember to `sudo chmod 777 myScript.py`, otherwise it fails saying that you don't have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write your own such utility using cronjob. This is how you can do this:

- Inspect some rss xml feed and you will find the `lastBuildDate` tag in it. This is the tag that tells you when the feed was last changed. For example, try viewing the source code for [this](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/europe/rss.xml) rss feed from BBC.
- Modify the script to inspect for the `lastBuildDate` tag to learn if the rss feed has been updated since the last check.
- Write a small cronjob to trigger the script you have written every `n` minutes. I have never used Raspbian but since its Debian based, it should support cronjobs. You can use `python-crontab` to write one. See [this](http://wuilly.com/manage-cron-jobs-with-python-crontab/) or [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/) to start with `python-crontab`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I was able to find a small tool to do exactly that, take a look at my own answer. Thanks anyways!